# tap doesn't work in ios xamarin.forms

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, mobile, layout, xamarin.forms

I have 2 grids: one overlaps the other...in my android project it works well but in my ios device the tapgesturerecognizer doesn't work. the tap is in the topper grid.
I tried input transparent in the under grid and put one of them inside a ContentView (someone told that it can be the answer, but unfortunately, it's not)...but nothing seems to work...I'm desperate...2 days searching for it, it's a job question and I think I will have problems because of that
Please, if you can, try to help me.
It's only two grids in the row 0 and column 0 of the other grid...
There isn't an error on logs...But the click doesnt arrive in the function that it should arrive.

The code

```
private void CriaTela()
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;

        gridtextura.RowSpacing = 5;
        gridtextura.ColumnSpacing = 15;

        lstCategorias = lstCategorias.OrderBy(o => o.nome).ToList();

        foreach (var item in lstCategorias)
        {
            Grid GridContent = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            var textura = new CachedImage();
            textura.Source = "texturaCateg";
            textura.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            textura.Aspect = Aspect.Fill;

            GridContent.BindingContext = item;

            Grid boxColorView = new Grid
            {
                RowSpacing = 0,
                //InputTransparent = true,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =
            {
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) },
                new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(8, GridUnitType.Star) }
            }
            };

            boxColorView.Children.Add(new StackLayout { BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(item.corFundo), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 1 );
            boxColorView.Children.Add(textura, 0, 1);

          //  boxColorView.Children.Add(new BoxView { VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 0);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(boxColorView, column, row);
            gridtextura.Children.Add(GridContent, column, row);

            //Qual categoria foi escolhida?
            var CliqueCategoria = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            CliqueCategoria.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            CliqueCategoria.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                CriaLoading();
                var stacklayout = s as Grid;
                categoriaEscolhida = (Categorias)stacklayout.BindingContext;
                ChamaProdutos();
            };

            GridContent.GestureRecognizers.Add(CliqueCategoria);

            if (item.imagem != null && item.imagem != "")
            {
                int initIndex = item.imagem.IndexOf(',');
                string image = "";

                image = item.imagem.Substring(initIndex + 1);

                try
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(image))), VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand }, 0, 0);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    GridContent.Children.Add(new CachedImage { Source = "error.png", VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, HeightRequest = 50, WidthRequest = 50 }, 0, 0);

                }
            }

            GridContent.Children.Add(new Label { Text = item.nome, TextColor = Color.FromHex(item.corTexto), FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)), FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand }, 0, 1 );

            if (column == 0)
            {
                column = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                column = 0;
                row++;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: all right now, I think